# How to manually collapse the breadcrumb region in oracle apex 5.0?

Tags: javascript, html, oracle, oracle-apex

I am working with oracle apex 5.0. The breadcrumb region currently has an event tied to it which sets the class of the region from 'class="t-Body-title"' to class="t-Body-title has-shadow t-Body-title-shrink". This also lowers the top margin for the content body to 86 instead of 142.  This event takes place when you scroll about halfway down the page and reverses itself once you scroll back up to the top. I am not sure how I can debug this change event in order to figure out where the event is being called. Does anyone know how I can capture this event or even set the breadcrumbs bar to be shrunk from the start?  Any suggestions or ideas are helpful, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this putting this line of code in the 'Execute on Page Load' attribute of your page:

```
 $(".t-Body-title").attr("class","t-Body-title has-shadow t-Body-title-shrink");
```

Answer (score 0):

To shrink the breadcrumb bar from the start, you can add the following css to your page

```
.t-BreadcrumbRegion--useBreadcrumbTitle .t-Breadcrumb-item:last-child {
font-size: 1.5rem !important;
line-height: 3.3rem !important;}

.t-BreadcrumbRegion-body,.t-BreadcrumbRegion-buttons {
padding-top:12px !important;
padding-bottom:12px !important;}
```